# Using screen on Synology (DSM6): "Cannot find termcap entry for 'xterm-256color"

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, synology

Using screen on Synology (DSM6) I get the error

> Cannot find termcap entry for 'xterm-256color'

when I type `screen`.

I am aware of the quick fix from this question [Unix screen utility error: Cannot find termcap entry for 'xterm-256color'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823994/unix-screen-utility-error-cannot-find-termcap-entry-for-xterm-256color).
So `TERM=xterm screen` does work and launches `screen`.

But I would like to set `TERM` to a different value on my machine, so I could just type `screen` instead.
Can I choose the color mode screen uses and set it somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen` filters out escape sequences which it does not support.  It doesn't support the xterm-style escape sequence which changes color values, but uses only the predefined color palette of your terminal.

If you do

```
infocmp screen-256color xterm-256color
```

you'll probably notice several differences.  The one dealing with changing color values is `initc`.  (Choosing a given color from the palette is done with `setaf` and `setab`).

The warning message is because (apparently) your machine does not have a terminal description for `xterm-256color` installed, e.g., if you ssh to the machine and it gets `TERM` from your local machine.  `screen` wants to know what `TERM` applies to *outside*, to help it convert to its *inside* (`TERM=screen`).  A quick read of the documentation and source code shows that while it has several features for *amending* the conversion between in/out `TERM`, and for choosing a particular inside-TERM, there is no `.screenrc` setting for overriding the environment variable `TERM`.

Here's a pointer to the [relevant chunk of code in `screen`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/screen.c#n695):

```
    if ((attach_term = getenv("TERM")) == 0 || *attach_term == 0)
        Panic(0, "Please set a terminal type.");
    if (strlen(attach_term) > MAXTERMLEN)
        Panic(0, "$TERM too long - sorry.");
    GetTTY(0, &attach_Mode);
```

where it ensures that `TERM` is set, and a pointer to (a couple of levels down) where [it checks if `TERM` corresponds to an actual terminal description](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/termcap.c#n98):

```
if (*D_termname == 0 || e_tgetent(tbuf, D_termname) != 1) {
    Msg(0, "Cannot find terminfo entry for '%s'.", D_termname);
    return -1;
}
```

So... if you want to just run "screen", you could make a shell alias, or simple script which sets `TERM` as you are doing now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure my question was very clear so I edited it. I would like to be able just to do `screen` with a predefined palette of my choice saved somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Using .bashrc you can set the TERM back to a working version. My issue was the screen.xterm-256color did not exist.

```
# ~/.screenrc
# Fix screen and vim
# "E437: terminal capability "cm" required"
if [[ $TERM = 'screen.xterm-256color' ]]; then
  export TERM=xterm-256color
fi
```

For the .bashrc changes to take effect in screen you need to tell screen to treat each terminal as a new shell

```
#~/.screenrc
# Treat all new screen tabs as new shells
shell -$SHELL
```